# Python: Check for unique characters on a String

Tags: python, string, character, unique

I'm asking the user to input a keyword and then remove any duplicate characters.

Example:

**Input**: balloon

**Output**: balon

I've tried this solution: [List of all unique characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13902805/python-list-of-all-unique-characters-in-a-string) but it marks it as a syntax error.

Any ideas?

Comment: post your exact code.

Comment: Just starting off with 
keyword = input('Keyword: ')
print(keyword)

Comment: How you tried? Can you show your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your answer, order is important.  Here is a one line solution:

```
word = raw_input()
reduced_word = ''.join(
    [char for index, char in enumerate(word) if char not in word[0:index]])
```

Comment: OrderedDict is the most straight-forward, efficent answer.  I was just puzzle-challenging myself and seeing if I could create a one-liner only using builtins to solve the problem!

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
In [4]: from collections import OrderedDict
In [5]: def rawInputTest():
   ...:    x = raw_input(">>> Input: ")
   ...:    print ''.join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(x).keys())
```

---

```
In [6]: rawInputTest()
>>> Input: balloon
balon
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
In [15]: from collections import OrderedDict

In [16]: s="ballon"

In [17]: od = OrderedDict.fromkeys(s).keys()

In [18]: print(od)
['b', 'a', 'l', 'o', 'n']

In [19]: "".join(od)
Out[19]: 'balon'
```

Comment: Do I need to import something to use OrderedDict?

Comment: Yep, forgot about `from collections import OrderedDict`

Comment: print(od) comes out as follows: KeysView(OrderedDict([('b', None), ('a', None), ('l', None), ('o', None), ('n', None)])).

Comment: It might be because I use ipython. However, the print result does not matter much IMO. What matters more is that it the answer preserves the order of characters, and the resulting string after `join` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are performing a set operation. If order is not import, just insert each character into a set and print the contents of the set when done. 
If the order is important, then create a set. For each character, if it is not in the set append it to a list and insert it into the set. Print the contents of the list in order when done.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict1 = {"cat":6,"rat":7,"dog":4,"elephent":20,"lion":15,"cow":9,"bat":4,"hen":2,"bird":2}

dic_values= dict1.values()

unique_val = set(dic_values)

print("dic_val :",dic_values)

print("unique_dict_valu :",unique_val)
```