# Python String Dissection

Tags: regex, string, python-3.5

Here is the problem:

1. Replace input string with the following: The first and last characters, separated by the count of distinct characters between the two.
2. Any non-alphabetic character in the input string should appear in the output string in its original relative location.

Here is the code I have thus far:

```
word = input("Please enter a word: ")
first_character = word[0]
last_character = word[-1]
unique_characters = (list(set(word[1:-1])))
unique_count = str(len(unique_characters))
print(first_character[0],unique_count,last_character[0])
```

For the second part, I have thought about using regex, however I have not been able to wrap my head around regex as it is not something I ever use.

Comment: Something like [this](https://ideone.com/kH5lik)? I guess `Testers` should be replaced with `T5s`.

Comment: No we only want the unique characters between the first and the last character. So T4s is correct.

Comment: Good, then https://ideone.com/IaYfBZ? `len(''.join(set(m.group(2))))` should get the count of the unique characters.

Comment: What about one letter words? They should be left as is, right? What about 2 letter words? `"Ts"` -> `T0s` or `Ts`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
import re
pat = r"\b([^\W\d_])([^\W\d_]*)([^\W\d_])\b"
s = "Testers"
print(re.sub(pat, (lambda m: "{0}{1}{2}".format(m.group(1), len(''.join(set(m.group(2)))), m.group(3))), s))
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/IaYfBZ).

The regex breakdown:

- `\b` - word boundary (use `^` if you test an individual string)
- `([^\W\d_])` - Group 1 capturing any ASCII letter (use `re.U` flag if you need to match Unicode, too)
- `([^\W\d_]*)` - Group 2 capturing zero or more letters
- `([^\W\d_])` -  Group 3 capturing a letter at...
- `\b` - the trailing word boundary (replace with `$` if you handle individual strings)

In the replacement pattern, the `len(''.join(set(m.group(2))))` is counting the number of unique letter occurrences ([see this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13902805/python-list-of-all-unique-characters-in-a-string)).

If you need to handle 2-letter words like `Ts` > `Ts`, you may replace `*` with `+` quantifier in the second group.

Comment: I tested with a string of `T3sters` and was expecting `T34s` as the output since the non-alpha characters are supposed to remain in the string, but got my original input as the output.

Comment: So, you do not expect the words to be whole words. I see. Just take out the `\b`s. But then, `T3sters` will yield `T3s3s`. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/SINwrJ). Also, the requirement for a word is that it should be *a sequence of alphabetic characters, delimited by any non-alphabetic characters.* So, `T3sters` cannot yield `T34s` as `3` is not an alphabetic character.