# Counting the occurrence of unique letters in a string in Python 3

Tags: string, python-3.x

There are many way for Counting the occurrence of unique letters in a string in Python 3. I just wanna know what is the best way for this job.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you are aware of the many ways to count the  occurrences of unique letters, you should be able to write a benchmark that compares them in order to determine which is best. This is not a homework completion service.

Comment: Please take a moment to read these- https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need to count characters in string, try the following

```
a = "aaabbcccd"
b = dict.fromkeys(a, 0)
for i in a:
    b[i] += 1
```

b now holds the counts you require:

```
{'a': 3, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 1}
```

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
''.join(set('aaabbbcccdddd'))
```

or:

```
list(set('aaabbbcccdddd'))
```

Also see the post: [List of all unique characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13902805/list-of-all-unique-characters-in-a-string)

Comment: i didn't meant that. imeant:
aabbcda
a 3
b 2
c 1
d 1