# Separate each letter from a text without saving the same letter twice

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I wanted to know how I could separate a text in the different letters it has without saving the same letter twice in python. So the output of a text like `"hello"` will be `{'h','e',l','o'}`, counting the letter `l` only once.

Comment: `set(list("hello"))` ?

Comment: Or even set(‘hello’)

Comment: I like to just do
`letters = [l for l in txt]`
Then converting it into a set, and back into a list.
`lis = list (set (letters))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of all unique characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13902805/list-of-all-unique-characters-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

As the comments say, put your word in a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) to remove duplicates:

```
>>> set("hello")
set(['h', 'e', 'l', 'o'])
```

Iterate through it (sets don't have order, so don't count on that):

```
>>> h = set("hello")
>>> for c in h:
...   print(c)
...
h
e
l
o
```

Test if a character is in it:

```
>>> 'e' in h
True
>>> 'x' in h
False
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to do this...

```
word = set('hello')
```

Or the following...

```
letters = []

for letter in "hello":
    if letter not in letters:
        letters.append(letter)
```